# Modal Dialogs in Monogame

Tags: c#, .net, xna, monogame

I'm looking to have modal dialogs in my game, for tutorial purposes. I can write my own fairly easily, but if there is a open source library out there that could help me with this, I would certainly prefer it. I've googled and didn't have much luck. Google seems to not get "Modal Dialog Monogame"

Comment: there are a few ways to do this. you probably need to be more specific with what you need? what platforms do you need to support?

Comment: I need to be able to support windows, android at this point and potentially iOS later. It will need to be coded in "monogame" essentially. I've got some in that are just a colored square with titles but I figured someone else has a nicer solution.